# ShowDialog() displays no data but Show() does

Tags: c#, wpf

Maybe this can't be answered without context but when I use `Show()`:

```
TestView test = new TestView()
            {

                Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow
            };
            test.Show();
```

Everything works fine, the events are fired and my textbox/comboboxes are populated with data on the test view. But when I use ShowDialog() nothing is populated. Anyone know a reason why? I want a modal window.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Out of curiosity, what you actually did?

Comment: I can't really show my code.  I just have prism events under the code above that publish values from this view to the test view which subscribes to these values and sets the properties which are mvvm binded comboboxes.

Comment: So those ComboBoxes are on TestView or the other Windows of your app?

Comment: my bad, the code above is in viewmodel (A) that publishes to the subscribing viewmodel (b), which has a view(window) with comboboxes. The viewmodel (A) has a usercontrol on mainwindow.

Comment: Thanks but still unclear to me. Those comboBoxes are on TestView you opened by ShowDialog? If so, it is unusual. But if no, it is quite normal and nothing surprising.

Comment: Yes haha, in this case they are on "TestView". I'm sorry that it might be confusing without the code...

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It sounds like so complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

As by [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0):

> When a Window class is instantiated, it is not visible by default. ShowDialog shows the window, disables all other windows in the application, and returns only when the window is closed. This type of window is known as a modal window.

> Modal windows are primarily used as dialog boxes. A dialog box is a special type of window that applications use to interact with users to complete tasks, such as opening files or printing documents. Dialog boxes commonly allow users to accept or cancel the task for which they were shown before the dialog box is closed.

Thus, the `ShowDialog` is blocking until the window is closed.

This means that dealing with events and similar, specifically from the Owner window will not work.

If you have additional questions, please show the relevant code with the events and how you populate them.

If for some reason you need a full blocking window - it is possible; but we will need more details.